# How to checkout from diff view?

Tags: diff, perforce, vcs-checkout

I am using Perforce 2015 client (P4V) on Windows 7.

I changed some files in my IDE. Then I use "Folder Diff" in Perforce to locate them. I was expecting to find "checkout" right click menu on the "Folder Diff" Perforce window in order to move my changes to a changeset but I don't see any "checkout" around.

How can I checkout directly from Diff view?

Answer (score 0):

If you changed files on your workstation, but Perforce doesn't know about those changes yet, the command you're looking for is "reconcile".

I believe that P4V's Folder Diff may only show you the reconcile options if you use Folder Diff from the Advanced Reconcile Options variant of Reconcile Offline Work.

So to perform this style of Folder Diff within P4V, you should start by context-clicking on the root folder in your tree view and choosing "Reconcile Offline Work", then choose the Advanced Reconcile button at the bottom of that display, as described here: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Offline.html

Then, when Advanced Reconcile opens up the Folder Diff, you will see suggestions in red lettering about what your options are for each file (Mark For Edit, Get Revision, ec.). You can then pick one of those options by context-clicking that file in Folder Diff.

Alternatively (and perhaps more useful, once you get used to it), you can do this from the command line. If you haven't worked directly with the command line before, you can context-click "Open Command Window Here" on the root folder of your workspace treeview to get to the command window. Then, type

```
p4 status
```

to see a report about what changes you have made to your files, and

```
p4 reconcile
```

to make those files open for add, edit, or delete, as appropriate. Then close the command window and refresh P4V to see them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your exact scenario and IDE is. I am using Visual Studio with the Perforce plugin, and when I make any changes in my source this plugin will check-out this file automatically (you can also choose to be prompted). So no need for folder diffs to locate any changes.

Should your IDE miss any integration plugin's then a very simple workflow could be like this:

- Go to Perforce and check out all the files in your solution
- Make your edits in your IDE (online or offline doesn't really matter)
- In Perforce choose 'Revert Unchanged Files' on the changelist

And voila, only the changed files will be left in your changelist, you can then review the changes and submit to the depot.

NB: should in the mean time another developer have made any changes to any of your changed files, Perforce will warn you that you need to execute a Get Latest and then Resolve (i.e. merge) the changes.